# Unhandled Exception with Convert class C#7.0

Tags: c#, constructor, io, unhandled-exception, c#-7.0

I am getting an exception error on line 20 saying that the user input is not of the correct type which is why I added the Convert class. I'm trying to get the properties to be read/write according to the user's input so that the radius of the circle will be accepted as an argument in the constructor.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace Project3
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Circle userCircle = new Circle();
            WriteLine("What is the radius of the circle?");
            userRadius = Convert.ToDouble(ReadLine());
            userCircle.Radius = Convert.ToDouble(ReadLine());

        GetArea();
        GetDiameter();
        GetCircumference();
    }
}

public class Circle
{
    const double pie = 3.14159;
    double area,
           circumference,
           diameter,
           userRadius;

    public double radius; //Data members
    public Circle(double radiusOfCircle) //Accepts radius of the circle as an argument
    {
        radiusOfCircle = radius;
    }

    public double Radius  //radius property set to default value of 0
    {
        get { return radius; }
        set { radius = value; }
    }

    public Circle() //default constructor 
    {

    }

    double GetArea()
    {
        area = pie * userRadius * userRadius;
        WriteLine("The Area is {0:##.##}", area);
        return area;
    }

    double GetDiameter()
    {
        diameter = userRadius * 2;
        WriteLine("The Diameter is {0:##.##}", diameter);
        return diameter;
    }

    double GetCircumference()
    {
        circumference = 2 * pie * userRadius;
        WriteLine("The Circumference is {0:##.##}", circumference);
        return circumference;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm actually not getting any compilation errors for this code. It's when I enter my first value for area and then press enter to try and proceed with the Main method. That's when it throws the unhanded exception.

Comment: Why wouldn't I declare it in the Main method? It's where program execution begins so I put it after lines 16-22 in order for it to be the first method executed after the user input values have been set. It works but the methods that follow generate the unhandled exception.

Comment: @MongZhu You are right, the code will not compile, also it might be a bad idea to refer to line numbers when we can't see any. Maybe check the difference pi vs pie and maybe you wanna use `Math.PI` constant (check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pi%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2).

Comment: @MongZhu I did not post different code, I'm using VS 2017. If you copy and paste the code from the question into VS, it compiles. You have to add another closing brace onto the end for the namespace but the code actually compiles. The first method works fine and as intended. When the GetArea() method is done the GetDiameter() method throws an unhandled exception. If you copy and paste the code, we should all have the same line numbers.

Comment: ok I haven't used VS 2017 and C# 7.0 yet. I apologize. You are right.  May be you should consider to add the C#7.0 Tag to your question.

Comment: @user3292642 actually I was wrong, just tried this code in VS2017 with C#7.0 and this stuff actually works now.... was quite surprised to see that it compiles

Comment: @MongZhu yeah I just downloaded VS2017 to try and check, really surprised me too...

Comment: Established, I moved the GetArea() method out of the Main() method. Please assist. Now I only have 4 errors stating that my methods are out of scope. Not sure where to move them exactly.

Comment: @CoadA Apparently this stuff works in C#7.0 so no need to move. But from a design perspective I would say: You need to be clear how to distribute the responsibilities, meaning what job is supposed to be done by whom? It is a good step to put the methods into the `Circle` class, since it seems to be the job of a circle to get those desired values. Now if the methods are inside the circle, then either the class needs the necessary Properties to make the calculations of you pass them as parameters into the methods. But you have already the `Radius` inside the `Circle` class. So just use it :)

Comment: Voting to close this as it's a "why isn't my code working" question with code that doesn't compile. Also, I don't see the purpose of the C# 7 tag here as nothing in the question relates to new language features in that version. Lastly, line 20 is a blank line so the question is meaningless as it currently stands.

Comment: @DavidArno This isn't a "why isn't my code working" question. The code compiles and it complies because C#7.0 enables for the usage of tuples, even though I'm not using one here. It's the reason why my methods are actually allowed to be 'declared' inside the Main method, I've moved them as of now but the code has always compiled. Reviewing the previous comments clarifies this.

Comment: Your original code, posted five hours ago - at the time of writing this - may well have compiled and included local functions. Thus at the time your C#7 tag made sense. The current code in your question though doesn't compile and doesn't contain local functions and has a blank line at line 20.

Comment: The code posted at this very moment gives only 4 errors stating my methods are out of scope as explained in my last comment (7 hrs ago). Not going to remove the C#7.0 tag because I'm using VS 2017 and C#7.0 which has new rules. Before I moved my methods out of the Main() method the code compiled because it thought I was creating a tuple (new to C#7.0) however, I was not. So if I would have put the code in VS 2015 it's safe to assume I would have went a different route at the prompt of a compile error BUT because I'm using VS 2017, I didn't get a compile error. Review past comments. @davidarno

Comment: So since you have now admitted that the code doesn't compile, what actually is your question, as you seem to still be claiming this isn't a "my code isn't working" question?

Comment: If I'm discussing the question with someone and they suggest edits, of course I'm going to make the edits which is exactly what I did. It's inevitable for you to come and say the question doesnt match the code. I made edits based off of the feedback (none from you) I was given. As I previously stated in a prior comment, I moved my method declarations and now the compiler states their out of context. If you would like to actually provide some help or links that would be greatly appreciated. Are you using the word function interchangeably with method?         C functions and C# methods difer

Answer (score 1):

When checking user input you should use the `Double.TryParse` method like this instead of using `Convert.ToDouble` which will throw an exception if it can't convert the input.

```
Double number;
var value = Console.ReadLine();
if (Double.TryParse(value, out number))
  Console.WriteLine(number);
else
  Console.WriteLine("{0} is outside the range of a Double.");
```

check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Did this compile for you? Or are you just showing me a brief example? @user3292642

Comment: Thank you @VMAtm. This helped